# I have problem in my flutter exsisting project

Tags: flutter

The error tells that i have not any /C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/fancy_bottom_navigation-0.3.3/lib/fancy_bottom_navigation.dart:111:7: Error: No named parameter with the name 'overflow'.
overflow: Overflow.visible,
^^^^^^^^
but i donot know where stack i use
[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ibD8R.png)

Answer (score 0):

go to that directory and replace `overflow: Overflow.visible` with `clipBehavior: Clip.none`

Comment: i do that but error is same

Comment: share your full code. if you want help.